# In Kodein dependency injection, how can you inject instances of Kodein itself into instances?

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin, kodein

In Kodein, I have modules imported into a parent module, and sometimes the classes need an instance of Kodein so they can do injection themselves later.  The problem is this code:

```kotlin
val parentModule = Kodein {
    import(SomeService.module)
}
```

Where `SomeService.module` needs the Kodein instance for later, but Kodein isn't yet created.  Passing it later into the module seems like a bad idea.

In Kodein `3.x` I see there is the `kodein-conf` module that has a global instance, but I want to avoid the global.

How do other modules or classes get the Kodein instance?

***Note:*** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Kotlin/Kodein topics are present in SO.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kodein `3.x` (and maybe older versions) you have access to a property within the initialization of any module called `kodein` that you can use in your bindings.

Within your module, the binding would look like:

```
bind<SomeService>() with singleton { SomeService(kodein) }
```

For a complete example and using a separation of interfaces vs. implementation, it might look something like this:

```
interface SomeService {
   // ...
}

class DefaultSomeService(val kodein: Kodein): SomeService {
    companion object {
        val module = Kodein.Module {
            bind<SomeService>() with singleton { DefaultSomeService(kodein) }
        }
    }

    val mapper: ObjectMapper = kodein.instance()
    // ...
}
```

You can import the module from the parent as you noted and it will receive its own reference to the current Kodein instance.

```
val kodein = Kodein {
    import(DefaultSomeService.module)
}
```