# With Kodein dependency injection, I don't want to pass around kodein instances everywhere

Tags: dependency-injection, kotlin, kodein

Using Kodein, I find I have to pass kodein instances around or inject them into modules and classes.  But sometimes I have classes that are so disconnected I want them just to be able to discover "one true Kodein".  Since this is a server side app, and I only have one Kodein scope it should be easy.  I can create a global object, such as:

```kotlin
val kodeinGlobal: Kodein = Kodein { ... }
```

But that doesn't work when some of the modules are re-used across different projects and we cannot easily share this one instance.  Maybe a separate module just to hold the global would work, but then it would need to be a `var` and I'd prefer it not be changeable.

Can Kodein find a main, top-level or global scope on its own?

***Note:*** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Kotlin/Kodein topics are present in SO.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kodein `3.x` there is a new module available called `kodein-conf`.  This allows you to create a modifiable instance of Kodein (as long as you modify it before the first injection is done), and it also contains a Kodein global instance for shared use if that is desired instead.  This is contrary to a normal Kodein instance which must have all bindings defined at construction time and can never be modified.

Using the predefined global is as easy as referencing `Kodein.global`.  And it works the same as any configurable Kodein instance:

```
Kodein.global.addImport(someModule) // add other modules to it

val something: SomethingCool = Kodein.global.instance() // inject from it
```

If you want to make your own global:

```
val kodeinGlobal = ConfigurableKodein()
```

For more about `ConfigurableKodein` read the [Kodein `3.x` docs for ConfigurableKodein](https://salomonbrys.github.io/Kodein/#_configurable_kodein), and about the predefined global instance [The God Complex: One True Kodein](https://salomonbrys.github.io/Kodein/#_the_god_complex_one_true_kodein)

As a helper, you can use the new `KodeinGlobalAware` interface to have natural access within your class to Kodein instances without having to directly reference the global Kodein instance.  For example by adding this interface, you can just call the instance creation methods, such as:

```
class DefaultSomeService(): SomeService, KodeinGlobalAware {
    val mapper: ObjectMapper = instance()
    // ...
}
```

Or if you have a case (such as testing) where you want to use the global instance unless overridden with a specific instance, you can do something similar to:

```
class DefaultSomeService(override val kodein: Kodein = Kodein.global): SomeService, KodeinAware {
    val mapper: ObjectMapper = instance()
    // ...
}
```

Which uses `KodeinAware` interface and and overrides its abstract member variable `kodein` to do the same transparent type of injection within the class, while defaulting to the `global` instance.

If you want to only inject Kodein whether that is the global instance or a specific one, see:  [Injecting Kodein instances within binding declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38572797/3679676) as an alternative.